# Within Delphi XE6 FTP GET() statement does not return after download finished

Tags: delphi, ftp, windows-10, indy, delphi-xe6

I have a problem with the idFTP Indy component trying to download a file from our server.  It downloads 99% of the file, and then just hangs.  The GET statement doesn't return.  All that has changed recently is that we've moved from Desktops running win 8.1 to laptops running win10.  If I write the progress and the full file size to the screen it downloads rather quickly until right at the end, and the last bytes just doesn't finish.  The file I'm trying to download is 15,573,350 Bytes.  It gets to about 14MB (rather quick) and stops.  I've tried downloading another file, and it's the same thing.

Any ideas?

Here is the code, there is nothing fancy about it.  I've copied it from our working app to try and test it, to see if it was something within the main project.

```
  with IdFTP1 do
  begin
    Host :=  'xxx';
    Username := 'xxx';
    Password := 'xxx';
    passive := True;
    Connect;
    ChangeDir('Service_Update');
    ChangeDir('QA');
    Self.Caption := Size('jam.zipper').tostring;
    TransferType := ftBinary; //tried with and without
    Get('jam.zipper','jam.zipper',true);
    Button1.Caption := 'Done'; //never gets here
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways `Get()` could freeze as you have described. Some ways include:

1. the server does not close the transfer connection *gracefully* at the end, or the server is not sending a final FTP response message on the command connection after the transfer is finished. Use a packet sniffer to verify.  To handle this, try assigning a non-infinite `ReadTimeout` on both command and transfer connections.
2. If the FTP session passes through a router/firewall that is not FTP-aware, the command connection may timeout and be dropped during a lengthy transfer. To handle this, `TIdFTP` has a `NATKeepAlive` property to configure TCP keep-alives on the command connection during transfers.
3. If you are using `TIdFTP` in a worker thread with event handlers that make unsynchronized calls to UI controls, this can cause all kinds of problems, including deadlocks. Always sync access to the UI.

Comment: Thank you Remy.  What tickles me is that the server didn't have any changes.  The downloading functionality has always worked - that is until I discovered now on win 10 that it doesn't any more.  Do you suppose this could make a difference?

For point 3, I am indeed using a thread.  But my actual working code behaves the same as my demo I've shared here.  It quickly downloads everything and then just doesn't do anything right at the end...

Comment: Ok, turns out I was wrong.  I reverted to win 8.1 to retest this and it's the same issue.  Must mean something has changed on the server side and I'll investigate that now...